# How does UPDATE FROM work?

Tags: postgresql

When trying to run this query, my assumption was that PostgreSQL will run the update twice on a row with id=0 having initial counter=0 and would end up with a counter=11 but it actually runs only once and results in counter=6.

Can someone please help figure out why? I have spent a good amount of time attempting to figure this out and can't seem to figure out why this is.

```
with duplicatedids as 
  ((select 0 as idx, 6 as v) union 
   (select 1 as idx, 5 as v))
update  verify_seq_update 
set counter = counter + duplicatedids.v 
from duplicatedids 
where verify_seq_update.id <= duplicatedids.idx ;
```

Comment: Btw, use `WITH duplicated_ids(idx, v) AS (VALUES (0, 6), (1, 5))` instead of the complicated `UNION` of single-row `SELECT`s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `UPDATE` can modify many rows but each of them will be modified only once.

For a more detailed explanation, see the [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) section of Postgres documentation:

> Notes
> ...   When using `FROM` you should **ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified**. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then **only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row**, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.